# (R) Write function with vector as variable

Tags: r, function

I want to create a function and use sapply to pass a number of input variables through it. The trick: the "variables" are actually vectors. I include an example below, where I would like to transpose the vectors `a`, `b`, and `d`, without having to manually write each command individually. I include the `x <-`  part, while leaving it blank, because this is one of the main points of my confusion. Were I creating a normal function, I would simply create a vector of all the variables I want to pass through form5. However, if I create a vector *from vectors*, I'll just have a longer vector. So to be clear, I'd like sapply to return a matrix or dataframe with all 3 transposed vectors.

```
a <- c(1:10)
b <- c(11:20)
d <- c(21:30)

X <- 

form5 <- function(x){ 
  t(x)
}

sapply(x, form5)
```

Comment: So like `sapply(list(a,b,d), form5)`? If you have related vectors, it would be easier to store them in a list to begin with rather than have a bunch of separate variables in your global environment.